# How to use upload component (upload xls, xlsx file) of ant design in react.js

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to use the upload component of ant design, but I don't understand how the props of this component work.

I wrote this code, but it doesn't work

```
<Upload name="file" accept=".xls, .xlsx">
 <Button icon={<UploadOutlined/>}>Click to upload</Button>
</Upload>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of using this component.

---

> **First**

When the file is selected, the component automatically sends this file to the endpoint has been set as the value of `action` property *(There should be a server to get and store this file when the endpoint is called).* In this situation you often should set headers (like `Authorization` header) for the Restful request that is being sent to the server as an API.

```
import { UploadOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { Button, message, Upload } from 'antd';
import { UploadChangeParam, UploadFile } from 'antd/es/upload';

function Test() {

  const uploadChanged = (event: UploadChangeParam<UploadFile<any>>) => {
    if (event.file.status !== 'uploading') {
      console.log(event.file, event.fileList);
    }
    if (event.file.status === 'done') {
      message.success(`${event.file.name} file uploaded successfully`);
    } else if (event.file.status === 'error') {
      message.error(`${event.file.name} file upload failed.`);
    }
  }

  return (
    <Upload
      name="file"
      action="https://EndPointForUploadingTheFile"
      headers={{
        authorization: 'the authorization token from the user',  //if needed
      }}
      accept=".xls, .xlsx"
      onChange={e => uploadChanged(e)}
    >
      <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Click to Upload</Button>
    </Upload>
  );
}
```

Notice that, with the help of `uploadChanged` callback function, you can check whether the file was uploaded or is being uploaded or the API has been failed.

---

> **Second**

You want to stop the automatic file uploader API, and store the uploaded files in a state until the form you are filling out is finished. Then send the whole form content (including these files) via the submit API to the server. You can do it by passing a callback which returns `false` through `beforeUpload` property like so:

```
import { UploadOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { Button, Upload } from 'antd';
import { UploadChangeParam, UploadFile } from 'antd/es/upload';
import { useState } from 'react'

function Test() {

  const [files, setFiles] = useState<UploadFile<any>[]>([])

  const uploadChanged = (event: UploadChangeParam<UploadFile<any>>) => {
     setFiles(event.fileList);
  }

  const fileRemoved = (event: UploadFile<any>) => {
    const filteredFiles = files.filter(file => file !== event);
    setFiles(filteredFiles);    
  }

  return (
    <Upload
      name="file"
      showUploadList={{ showRemoveIcon: true }}
      accept=".xls, .xlsx"
      beforeUpload={() => false}
      onChange={e => uploadChanged(e)}
      onRemove={e => fileRemoved(e)}
    >
      <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Click to Upload</Button>
    </Upload>
  );
}
```

**PS**: When the `Upload` component content is changed, the list of the uploaded files in `Upload` is stored in `files` state (by `uploadChanged` callback). Also when one of the files in `Upload` is removed, `fileRemoved` callback omits that file from the `files` state to keep the `files` and `Upload` content the same.